# How to execute list of "android update project" commands in single batch file on Windows XP?

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, batch-file

I have created a batch file to build apk file for a set of android projects (A MainProject along with 3 library project) created using eclipse

It is properly compiled in eclipse, But it is not compiled properly through batch file (bcos only first statement in batch file getting executed).

The following is the code present in batch file

```
cd C:\MainFoldere\
set ANT_HOME=C:\apache-ant-1.9.1\
set JAVA_HOME=c:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk\tools
android update project -p ./Library1 --subprojects --target 1
cd C:\MainFoldere\\Library1 
ant clean
ant debug
cd .. 
android update project -p ./Library2 --library ../Library1 --subprojects --target 1
cd C:\MainFoldere\\Library2
ant clean
ant debug
cd .. 
android update project -p ./Library3 --library ../Library2 --subprojects --target 1
cd C:\MainFoldere\\Library3
ant clean
ant debug
cd .. 
android update project -p ./MainProject --library ../Library3 --subprojects --target 1
cd C:\MainFoldere\\MainProject
ant clean
ant debug
```

Comment: `bcos only first statement in batch file getting executed` - what do you mean and how do you know?

Comment: I tried with running the batch file in command prompt like `c:>batch.bat` and It runs the first command `android update project -p ./Library1 --subprojects --target 1` and stopped at prompt `c:>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add CALL before each line and it will execute all the commands

Comment: Excellent, Thank you very much dude :). It is working now :). But I am not understanding, Why it was previously not running? I am curious to know what happened early.

Comment: Normally CALL is used to run another batch file within a batch file. When the batch file that is called is completed, the remainder of the original batch file is completed.

you can as well use CALL to 
    call another command file and return to this one when it's       done. ; or
    call a function in the current command file.

Comment: Thanks user1283633, Now I understand the purpose of CALL. Thank you so much :)